# PyQt5 Disable edit menu when QTextEdit loses focus unless the focus is lost to the edit menu

Tags: python, menu, pyqt5, focus, qtextedit

I have subclassed QTextEdit to detect the change in focus as follows:

```
    GotFocus = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    def focusInEvent(self, event):
        self.GotFocus.emit()
        super().focusInEvent(event)

    LostFocus = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    def focusOutEvent(self, event):
        self.LostFocus.emit()
        super().focusOutEvent(event)
```

I then connect the LostFocus event to on_myTextBox_lost_focus.

```
    def on_myTextBox_lost_focus(self):
        self.editMenu.setEnabled(False)
```

Of course, this gives strange behavior if the focus is lost to the edit menu. I can't figure out how to check for this. It seems that the focus is lost before the menu's about to show signal. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Solved. Many thanks to ekhumoro. Emit a lost focus signal only if the focus is not lost to a menu.

```
    LostFocus = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    def focusOutEvent(self, event):
        if event.reason() != 4 and event.reason() != 6:
            self.LostFocus.emit()
        super().focusOutEvent(event)
```

Comment: Forget about the focus events. Use the menu's aboutToShow signal and check whether the text-edit [has the focus](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#focus-prop).

Comment: @ekhumoro unless the OP wants to disable the menuAction() of the menu in a menubar or parent menu?

Comment: @musicamante Personally, I would say that's poor ui design, because it prevents user-discovery. But anyway, on second thoughts, my suggestion won't work properly, because the signal happens at the wrong time. Probably the right solution is to check the [focus reason](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#FocusReason-enum) to decide when to emit the focus-change signals.